# How do I make unnumbered lists in Markdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, markdown, octopress

I want to have this kind of lists:

- asdasdas
- aqweqwe

Instead of

1. asdasdasdas
2. jasdasdasda

Please help

Comment: Have you read the Markdown syntax guide? http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the Markdown syntax guide](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list). In it's chapter about lists it says:

> Unordered lists use asterisks, pluses, and hyphens — interchangably —
>   as list markers:
>
> ```
> *   Red
> *   Green
> *   Blue
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> +   Red
> +   Green
> +   Blue
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> -   Red
> -   Green
> -   Blue
> ```